# SCP reproducably breaks SSH pipe

Tags: ssh, openvpn, scp

I'm trying to copy some certificates onto my server using `scp`.

```
$ scp ./cert.* sshuser@192.168.0.42:/tmp/

cert.crt     100% 2386     0.1KB/s   00:18
packet_write_wait: Connection to 192.168.0.42 port 22: Broken pipe
lost connection
```

The first file is written to the server, but not completely as the hashsum does not match with the original file.

This happens every time I try to `scp` these files (`crt`, `key` and `p12`).

Tested with Ubuntu 16.10 (`OpenSSH_7.3p1 Ubuntu-1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016`)
and with Windows 10 (`WinSCP 5.9.4`). Both fail copying the files.

It may be worth mentioning that I'm connected to an OpenVPN server, in order to reach the target server (192.168.0.42) - but that shouldn't be an issue.

**Why does the pipe break and how can I successfully scp the files onto the server?**

*edit:* This, as suggested in the comments, most likely has to do with the MTU - however, I'm not quite sure how to fix this issue yet.

Comment: Have you tried lowering your MTU on the server side or clamping the MTU to take into account the OpenVPN overhead ?

Comment: I'll give it a shot, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @davidgo I wouldn't want to modify the server, as others use it too. What would you suggest for the client side? Lowering/increasing the OpenVPN MTU?

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/127369/how-to-prevent-write-failed-broken-pipe-on-ssh-connection

Comment: @Gnudiff thank you, but most of the answers suggest that the session is not kept alive for the duration required. My transfer should be done within seconds.

Comment: Does it only happen for those files, or for any files? From your post it wasn't clear. Also, can you try scp with -v option and post output?

Comment: It appears that files/data over a certain size cause the pipe to break - so I assume @davidgo was quite right and this is an issue with the MTU.

Comment: If the content of the files is copy/pasted in batches of a few lines it works. If the complete text is copied and pasted, the pipe breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lowering the MTU of the OpenVPN connection worked for me.

From the OpenVPN manual:

> --mssfix max
>       Announce to TCP sessions running over the tunnel that they should limit their send packet sizes such that after OpenVPN has encapsulated
>   them, the resulting UDP packet size that OpenVPN sends to its peer
>   will not exceed max bytes. The default value is 1450.
>
> The max parameter is interpreted in the same way as the --link-mtu parameter, i.e. the UDP packet size after encapsulation overhead has
>   been added in, but not including the UDP header itself. Resulting
>   packet would be at most 28 bytes larger for IPv4 and 48 bytes for IPv6
>   (20/40 bytes for IP header and 8 bytes for UDP header). Default value
>   of 1450 allows IPv4 packets to be transmitted over a link with MTU
>   1473 or higher without IP level fragmentation.
>
> The --mssfix option only makes sense when you are using the UDP protocol for OpenVPN peer-to-peer communication, i.e. --proto udp.
>
> --mssfix and --fragment can be ideally used together, where --mssfix will try to keep TCP from needing packet fragmentation in the first place, and if big packets come through anyhow (from protocols
>   other than TCP), --fragment will internally fragment them.
>
> Both --fragment and --mssfix are designed to work around cases where Path MTU discovery is broken on the network path between OpenVPN
>   peers.
>
> The usual symptom of such a breakdown is an OpenVPN connection which successfully starts, but then stalls during active usage.
>
> If --fragment and --mssfix are used together, --mssfix will take its default max parameter from the --fragment max option.
>
> Therefore, one could lower the maximum UDP packet size to 1300 (a good first try for solving MTU-related connection problems) with the
>   following options:
>
> --tun-mtu 1500 --fragment 1300 --mssfix

I added the following the to OpenVPN configuration:

```
mssfix 1200
```

I also assume that this value may be tweaked for better performance.