# Some commands just hang

Tags: bash

I have a Linux box, and am able to login using ssh. My shell is `/bin/bash`, I end up at a bash shell prompt.

I can execute bash built-in commands like `echo`. I am able to execute some commands from (prefixing path) `/bin` like `ls /bin`

Other commands like `whoami` appear to hang.  I CTRL-C and return to the bash prompt.

And other commands get completely hung, CTRL-C does not exit the command and I do not return to the bash prompt. `ls /usr/bin` is an example of a command that has hung the shell.

here is the path... because I know someone will ask about it...

```
$ echo $PATH  
/u01/jdk/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/u01/app/oracle/tools/home/oracle/bin
```

What would cause such a situation? What can I do to resolve the problem?

Comment: What is your default login shell? `getent passwd "$LOGNAME"` or `cat /etc/passwd | grep "$USER"`

Comment: updated q with answer to Jesse_b question.

Comment: Do you administer this machine? If so, does `dmesg` contain anything about errors — particularly disk errors (start at the bottom and read upwards — the top may have a bunch of unimportant boot messages). (If someone else administers it, I doubt there is much you can do to fix it. At least if it's disk errors).

Comment: we need more information, it could also be something like a hung or slow LDAP server, or ... (try stracing things, or equivalent?)

Comment: If it's everything that needs to read usernames (username-uid mappings), hung LDAP server or such; if it's everything related to a certain path, a hung network drive is one possibility; if it's totally everything, then it's possible you have an unbearable number of tasks in the run queue, and/or a huge I/O load. Or something completely different.

Comment: For a related question, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412192/ .

Comment: once upon a time booting into single user mode (the rescue shell was also single user) would behave like that. Are you sure you are not in single user mode?

Comment: It could be a problem with user space. Or maybe it's a physical problem, if `ls` is able to work with `/bin` and not `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Is /u01 an nfs mount, by any chance?

Comment: "commands like whoami appear to hang".  Knowing the other commands affected would help identify a common factor.

Answer (score 1):

derobert already mentioned `dmesg` in the comments. Try running it using an absolute path, like this:

```
/bin/dmesg | /bin/more
```

See if there are anything that would seem like a disk error: it might be that one of the directories listed in your `PATH` is on a disk that's failing. If the disk is failing in a way that causes it to get stuck, forever retrying the failing read operation, that might be causing the shell to hang when it is searching for a command to execute.

You could also try just minimizing the `PATH`: initially just set

```
PATH=/bin:/sbin
```

If you now can run commands without hanging and without using absolute paths, add back `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin` too.

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Now you should have all the standard commands available to you without using absolute paths. If the hanging phenomenon does not re-occur, you can now start checking the remaining directories.

As a quick check, you can use the `ls` command, but run it in the background so you won't cause your current session to become unusable if the command hangs. For example:

```
ls /u01/jdk/bin &
```

If you see the `ls` command output, just press Enter once to see the prompt again. (You will probably also see a message from the shell indicating that a  backgrounded command did just complete.)

If the output of `ls` won't appear or is clearly incomplete, check the output of the `dmesg` command again: you might find the kernel is now spewing disk I/O errors to the end of the output. Those error messages could be used to identify the failing disk device, but by knowing exactly at which path the `ls` command failed, you may already have a fairly good idea of that.