# SSH using Putty is closing connection in 20 seconds even while I'm executing commands

Tags: ssh, putty

I have launched an EC2 instance running ubuntu 16.4 and able to connect using Pytty SSH with Key pair. The issues is even when I'm executing some commands - that is actively working, the session closes every 20 seconds. If I restart the session, I can connect, closes after 20 seconds again. 
I tried to configure "Seconds between keepalives" to 10 or 20 or any other number, save the session, reopen the connection, I still have the same problem.
I also tried to enable TCP_KeepAlives checked, but the problem persists.

I was able to work properly earlier, but I am having the above problem for the past 2 days.

Comment: Window pops up with "Server unexpectedly closed network connection"

Comment: No. I'm connecting only one session.The last message on the putty log is 
Event Log: Server unexpectedly closed network connection

Comment: I can reproduce the error you're getting if I manually kill the sshd process that spawns my session. I suspect your remote sshd process(es) are being killed by something.

Comment: A related, but different, question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412192/ .

Answer (score 2):

Finally got the problem fixed.
all the while I was using my mobile hotspot to connect. This is 4G connection and I get good internet speed and connectivity. For some reason I had changed the cellular connection type to LTE only on mobile to increase the speed, though it did not really improve the speed, caused this problem.
when I reset back to LTE/CDMA which was the preferred network type, all things are fine now.

Thanks to all those who shared their views

Comment: I facing the same issue while using mobile internet(AirTel). My mobile doesn't have the option to switch between LTE and LTE/CDMA. I tried turning off VoLTE, didn't had any effect.

Comment: You saved my day, thank you. I swapped from my home wifi to cell phone and it worked. Changing ssh client's or sshd server's configuration (ServerAliveInterval, ClientAliveInterval etc..) didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I just noticed that, after swapping to my home wifi again, it is also working. Same configuration, weird...

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on a AWS Linux AMI instance recently. Should apply to others as well.  Changing the server side keep alives worked for me:

- Edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config
- Add ClientAliveInterval 120
- Restart sshd service

Comment: I tried this option, but the result is the same